# Logging information in AWS lambda while developing aws api's

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am new to building AWS API's using lambda functions. I want to be able to log information from all my lambdas for troubleshooting if I run into issues. I googled and found a lot of ways to do this. An example of one way can be found below.

```
        import logging
        logger = logging.getLogger()
        logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

        def my_logging_handler(event, context):
            logger.info('got event{}'.format(event))
            logger.error('something went wrong')
```

I have 2 questions. Is this a good approach? I am looking for a standard industry practice.
Is there a way to also update logs for lambdas to use a data protection policy?

Comment: See [Accessing Amazon CloudWatch logs for AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-cloudwatchlogs.html) and  [CloudWatch Logs retention policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/managedservices/latest/userguide/log-customize-retention.html).